# Not able to login in Microsoft SQL Management studio.(Error: Cannot connect to machine)

Tags: sql-server, authentication, connect

I have installed new setup of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio using `SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe` on Windows 8. Installations was completed successfully.

But I am not able to login using default logins e.g

- server name: `(local)`, machine name, `.`
- login: `sa`
- password: Password123,blank password.

PFB the error.

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to Dell.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Comment: Is login access enabled for the "sa" account?

Answer (score 1):

Go to

```
Start > SQL Server (xx) > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager
```

You should see a screen something like this:

[image]

When you select `SQL Server Services` on the left, you should see the running SQL Server services on the right. There should be *at least one* entry that looks like

```
Name                         State
------------------------------------
SQL Server (instancename)    Running
```

If there is no such entry --> you just simply **don't have SQL Server** (the database engine) installed. To fix it : install the **database engine**.

If you have an entry, the `(instancename)` becomes important:

- if it's `MSSQLSERVER`, you're dealing with a **default, unnamed** instance - you should be able to connect to it using `.`, `(local)` or your machine name
- if it's something else - then that something else is your **instance name**, and you need to connect to it using `.\instancename`, `(local)\instancename`

Typically, SQL Server **Express** editions are installed (by default) as `SQLEXPRESS` instances.

Comment: Thanks dear,Now its working, Earlier issue was that database engine was not installed only SQL management studio was installed.

Comment: @sahil: if you feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.